# Swift Show modal over modal possible without dissmiss parent?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I´m currently testing some popover modals in my iOS App. 
I have a Dialog with displays a second Dialog on of it.
I cal the second Dialog like this:

```
let vc = UISToryBoard(name, bundle).instantiateVC(identifier) as MyVC
self.present(vc,animate)
```

This works but my Caller ViewController gets dismissed and class viewDidDisapeared(). Is there some way to stack the modal popovers without dismissing the parent VC which calls the second modal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You caller view controller will not `dismiss` until you calls the `self.dismiss(animated: <#Bool#>, completion:nil)`

You are opening another view controller which is on top on your current view controller.

You should know about the [view controller life cycle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller)

Current view is `disappearing` and going to show another view controller's view. So that your current view controller's `viewDidDisapeared()` method is getting called. It's not meant by your current view controller is dismissed. It's just disappearing from visible.

Once you dismiss the second view controller your previous view's `viewWillAppear(_)` will trigger again.

Comment: okay yeah your are right. But is there a possiblity to prevent the caller view from disapearing?

Comment: Nope. Life cycle method will trigger